# Изменить нотацию Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans

Rак застваить Netbeans  8.0.2 (русский) форматировать код по такому шаблону:

```
 <?php
    'log'=>array
    (
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array
        (
            array
            (
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
            /*
            array
            (
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            ),
            */
        ),
    ),
?>
```

То есть на каком уровне скобки (фигурные или обычные) открываются, на таком и закрываются, а внутри них табуляция.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=52194&p=417734#p417734